# init restore from deep glacier on all files in aws s3 bucket using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an AWS s3 bucket with a lifecycle attached to it. The lifecycle has moved all the files into Deep glacier.

Now I want to restore all of them. Unfortunately in the GUI (s3 console) I cannot select the entire bucket or parent folder and simple click "init restore". I can only select files individually which is very tedious.

Therefore I thought about using aws cli.

I figured out the command to list all Deep Archive files already:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket my-backup-bucket --query "Contents[?StorageClass=='DEEP_ARCHIVE']" --output text
```

However, I would need a command to init restore on all the files listed by the command above. Any idea how to do that?

(there are many related questions, but I didn't find one matching my exact setup using aws cli)